# Trying restart vsftpd after install and configure - stop: Unknown instance:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vsftpd

After install and configure `vsftpd` I am trying restart service but got current error. I google a lot but did not found a good solution. I have `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)`

```
root:~# sudo service vsftpd restart
stop: Unknown instance:
vsftpd start/pre-start, process 6853
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution
I just start use ftp server called

> proftpd

Instead of this one